# searching for words in text paragraph and then flagging them in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a text data set, and want to search for various words in it, then flag those when when I find them. Here is sample data:

```
df <- data.table("id" = c(1:3), "report" = c("Travel opens our eyes to art, history, and culture – but it also introduces us to culinary adventures we may have never imagined otherwise."
                                             , "We quickly observed that no one in Sicily cooks with recipes (just with the heart), so we now do the same."
                                             , "We quickly observed that no one in Sicily cooks with recipes so we now do the same."), "summary" = c("On our first trip to Sicily to discover our family roots,"
                                                                      , "If you’re not a gardener, an Internet search for where to find zucchini flowers results."
                                                                      , "add some fresh cream to make the mixture a bit more liquid,"))
```

So far I have been using SQL to process through this, but it gets challenging when you have a lot list of words to look for.

```
dfOne <- sqldf("select id
              , case when lower(report) like '%opens%' then 1 else 0 end as opens
, case when lower(report) like '%cooks%' then 1 else 0 end as cooks
, case when lower(report) like '%internet%' then 1 else 0 end as internet
, case when lower(report) like '%zucchini%' then 1 else 0 end as zucchini
, case when lower(report) like '%fresh%' then 1 else 0 end as fresh
      from df
      ")
```

I'm looking for ideas to do this in a more efficient way. Imagine if you have a long list of target terms, this code can get unnecessarily too long.

Thanks,

SM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) sqldf**

Define the vector of words and then convert it to SQL.  Note that `case when` is not needed since `like` already produces a 0/1 result.  Prefacing `sqldf` with `fn$` enables `$like` to substitute the R `like` character string into the SQL statement.  Use the `verbose=TRUE` argument to `sqldf` to view the SQL statement generated.  This is only two lines of code no matter how long `words` is.

```
words <- c("opens", "cooks", "internet", "zucchini", "fresh", "test me")

like <- toString(sprintf("\nlower(report) like '%%%s%%' as '%s'", words, words))
fn$sqldf("select id, $like from df", verbose = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  id opens cooks internet zucchini fresh test me
1  1     1     0        0        0     0       0
2  2     0     1        0        0     0       0
3  3     0     1        0        0     0       0
```

**2) outer**

Using `words` from above we can use `outer` as follows.  Note that the function (third argument) in outer must be vectorized and we can make `grepl` vectorized as shown.  Omit `check.names = FALSE` if you don't mind the column names associated with words having spaces or puncutation munged into syntactic R variable names.  This produces the same output as (1).

```
with(df, data.frame(
    id, 
    +t(outer(setNames(words, words), report, Vectorize(grepl))), 
    check.names = FALSE
))
```

**3) sapply**

Using `sapply` we can get a slightly shorter solution along the same lines as (2).  The output is the same as in (1) and (2).

```
with(df, data.frame(id, +sapply(words, grepl, report), check.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: I like that your code is a few lines. I'll test it and accept the solution if it checks out. Thank you so much for weighing in.

Comment: Thank you G. Grothendieck. Solution 1 fails when something like this "test-me" or "test me" is used in the word list ``` words <- c("opens", "cooks", "internet", "zucchini", "fresh", "test me")``` . The other two work fine and create columns with names test.me. I think the first one has to do with naming conventions for column names in sqlLite?

Comment: The question did not seem to define words as having  punctuation or spaces but if you have such then just put quotes around the column name in the SQL statement.  I have modified it above to do that.  Also add check.names=FALSE to (2) and (3)  if you don't want name munging -- which we also did above.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll look into these functions and understand what they are doing under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse way. It assumes that you want to search two separate columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id = c(1:3), report = c("Travel opens our eyes to art, history, and culture – but it also introduces us to culinary adventures we may have never imagined otherwise."
                                             , "We quickly observed that no one in Sicily cooks with recipes (just with the heart), so we now do the same."
                                             , "We quickly observed that no one in Sicily cooks with recipes so we now do the same."), 
                 summary = c("On our first trip to Sicily to discover our family roots,"
                                                                                                                                                     , "If you’re not a gardener, an Internet search for where to find zucchini flowers results."
                                                                                                                                                     , "add some fresh cream to make the mixture a bit more liquid,"))


# Vector of words
vec <- c('eyes','art','gardener','mixture','trip')

df %>% 
  mutate(reportFlag = case_when(
    str_detect(report,paste(vec,collapse = '|')) ~ T,
    T ~ F)
) %>% 
  mutate(summaryFlag = case_when(
    str_detect(report,paste(vec,collapse = '|')) ~ T,
    T ~ F))
```

Comment: ok, this looks like an elegant solution. However I can't test it yet, I have issues installing tidyverse. Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'broom', 'rlang', 'tidyselect', 'vctrs' are not available for package 'modelr'. I'll solve this and evaluate your solution. In the mean time what does ~ T, T, F do?

Comment: Yeah thats some, less than intuitive, `case_when` syntax. The first argument `str_detect...` looks for words and flags T if it's found. If not, all other cases are marked with F. Thats the last T.

Comment: Does your solution create 5 new columns like my sql does? Each column for each word? Showing a 1 for a row or case with that word, and 0 otherwise?